# Where is there PHP executable in this docker?

Tags: php, docker, github, ubuntu-20.04, codelite

I use Ubuntu 20.04.
I installed this: https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql

I set PHP 8.1.
Install completed.

http://localhost:8000/ in Firefox is work.

I use CodeLite IDE on my desktop Ubuntu. I run CodeLite - PHP Setting - General - PHP Executable.

1. Where is there PHP executable in this docker for CodeLite IDE?
2. How do I run PHP script in command line in this docker?

My issue have not answer: https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/issues/63

Comment: So you asked the package developers' for the same thing *yesterday*, they didn't reply to you yet, and you ask the same thing on SO?

Comment: mrodo, yes, it is.

Comment: mrodo, 3 days ago